# Not loading Knockout.js

Tags: jquery, scripting, knockout.js, loading

I'm trying to create my own jQuery widget of sorts. I have all of my HTML and jQuery written, and I'm trying to dynamically add it to a page using:

```
<div class='searchbar'></div>
```

The widget uses Knockout.js, and a good deal of code that I wrote myself. The problem I'm running into [I suspect] deals with load order of my scripts.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Timestamp: 11/20/2012 9:26:13 AM
Error: Error: Unable to parse binding attribute.
Message: SyntaxError: syntax error;
Attribute value: value: query, valueUpdate: 
Source File: http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-1.2.1.js
Line: 44
```

If I comment out the Knockout binding block, everything works (minus having the values for the dropdown). Not sure why it's not making it through this code.

My jQuery is below, but a live version of what it's currently doing is available **[HERE](http://jonathonmoore.com/proto/index2.html)**. **[THIS](http://jonathonmoore.com/proto/)** is a working version without trying to load everything in dynamically, just so you know what it's supposed to look like.

```
(function() {

    var jQuery;

    /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.8.0') {
        var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        script_tag.setAttribute("src",
            "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js");
        if (script_tag.readyState) {
          script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
              if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                  scriptLoadHandler();
              }
          };
        } else {
          script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
        }
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
    } else {
        jQuery = window.jQuery;
        main();
    }

    /******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
    function scriptLoadHandler() {
        jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
        main(); 
    }

    /******** Our main function ********/
    function main() { 
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $("head").append("<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />");         
            $.getScript("http://knockoutjs.com/js/jquery.tmpl.js", function(){});
            $.getScript("http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-1.2.1.js", function(){});

            $(".searchBox").append("<div id='refine'>Creator</div>");
            $(".searchBox").append("<input class='inline' placeholder='Search...' size='30' type='text' id='search' data-bind='value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'' autocomplete='off' />");
            $(".searchBox").append("<div id='submit'>Search</div>");
            $(".searchBox").append("<div id='refineDropdown'><ul id='refineList'></ul></div>");
            $(".searchBox").append("<div id='dropdown'><ul data-bind=\"template: { name:'obj', foreach:objects }, click: function(){ $('.listObjItem').on('click', function(){ $('#search').val($(this).text()); $('#dropdown').hide(); $('#search').focus();});}\"></ul></div>");
            $(".searchBox").append("<script type='text/html' id='obj'><li class='listObjItem'><span data-bind='text: name'></span>&nbsp;in&nbsp;<strong data-bind='text: type'></strong></li></script>");

            /* Begin Knockout Bindings */

            var objects = [
              {name:"Pacers Game",              type:"Activities"},
              {name:"Colts Game",               type:"Activities"},
              {name:"Ice Game",                 type:"Activities"},
              {name:"Indians Game",             type:"Activities"},
              {name:"Fever Game",               type:"Activities"},
              {name:"Purdue Game",              type:"Activities"},
              {name:"Campaign Posters",         type:"Projects"},
              {name:"Campaign Media",           type:"Projects"},
              {name:"Event Booking",            type:"Projects"},
              {name:"New Product Seminar",      type:"Projects"},
              {name:"State Fair",               type:"Projects"},
              {name:"Draft Designs",            type:"Tasks"},
              {name:"Design Posters",           type:"Tasks"},
              {name:"Review Designs",           type:"Tasks"},
              {name:"Book Venue",               type:"Tasks"},
              {name:"Decorate ICC",             type:"Tasks"},
              {name:"Book Live Music",          type:"Tasks"},
              {name:"Arrange for DJ Payment",   type:"Tasks"},
              {name:"Event Cleanup",            type:"Tasks"}
            ];

            var viewModel = { query: ko.observable('') };

            viewModel.objects = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
                var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
                return ko.utils.arrayFilter(objects, function(obj) {
                    return obj.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
                });
            }, viewModel);

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

            /* End Knockout Bindings */

            var refine = ["All", "ID", "Creator", "Name", "Description", "Last Modified"];

            refine = refine.sort();
            for (var i = 0; i < refine.length; i++)
                $('#refineList').append('<li>' + refine[i] + '</li>');

            testLength();
            $("#dropdown").hide();
            $("#refineDropdown").hide();

            if($.browser.chrome) {
                $('#search').css('height','26px');
                $('#search').css('padding','0px 5px 0px 5px');
                $('#refine').css('margin-right','-3px');
            }
            else if($.browser.mozilla) {
                $('#search').css('height','25px');
                $('#search').css('padding','0px 5px 0px 5px');
                $('#search').css('margin-top','-6px');
                $('#refine').css('margin-right','-1px');
            }
            else if($.browser.msie) {
                $('#search').css('height','22px');
                $('#search').css('padding','4px 5px 0px 5px');
            }

            var $hidden = $('#hidden');
            $("input").keyup(function(e) {
                testLength();
                $('#refine').removeClass('refineClicked');
                $('#refineDropdown').hide();
                if (this.value.length) {
                    var that = this;
                    $("#dropdown li").each(function() {
                        if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(that.value.toLowerCase()) == -1) $(this).appendTo($hidden);
                    });
                    $('#hidden li').each(function() {
                        if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(that.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1) $(this).appendTo('#list');
                    });
                    $("#search").css('border-bottom-right-radius', '0px');
                    $("#dropdown").show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#dropdown").hide();
                }
                if (e.which !== 40 && e.which !== 38) {
                    $('#dropdown li,#hidden li').each(function() {
                        $(this).removeClass('selected');
                    });
                    liSelected = null;
                }
            });

            $('#dropdown li').click(function() {
                $('#search').val($(this).text());
                $('#search').focus();
                $("#dropdown").hide();
            });

            var li = $('li');
            var liSelected;

            $('input').keydown(function(e) {
                liSelected = $('#dropdown .selected');

                if (e.which === 40) { // down-arrow
                    if (liSelected.length) {
                        var next = liSelected.next();

                        if (next.length) {
                            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
                            liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        liSelected = $('#dropdown li').eq(0).addClass('selected');
                    }
                }
                else if (e.which === 38) { // up-arrow
                    if (liSelected.length) {
                        var prev = liSelected.prev();

                        if (prev.length) {
                            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
                            liSelected = prev.addClass('selected');
                        }
                        else {
                            liSelected = $('#dropdown li').eq(-1).addClass('selected');
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
                    }
                }
                else if (e.which === 13) {
                    $('#search').val(liSelected.text());
                    $("#dropdown").hide()
                    $('#search').blur();
                }
            });

            $('#refine').click(function() {
                $("#dropdown").hide();
                if (!$('#refine').hasClass('refineClicked')) {
                    $('#refine').addClass('refineClicked');
                    $('#refineDropdown').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('#refine').removeClass('refineClicked');
                    $('#refineDropdown').hide();
                }
            });

            $('#refineDropdown li').click(function() {
                var tmp = $('#refine').width();
                $('#refine').html($(this).text());
                $('#refine').removeClass('refineClicked');
                $("#refineDropdown").hide();
                testLength();
                $('#search').css('width', $('#search').width() + (tmp - $('#refine').width()));
            });

            $('#submit').click(function() {
                alert('Searching for ' + $('#search').val() + '...');
            }); 

            function testLength() {
                if ($('#refine').text().length > 7) {
                    $('#refine').html($('#refine').text().substring(0, 6) + "...");
                }
                $('#dropdown').css('width', $('#search').width() + 4);

                if($.browser.chrome)
                    $('#dropdown').css('margin-left', $('#refine').width() + 11);
                else
                    $('#dropdown').css('margin-left', $('#refine').width() + 13);
            }
        });
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. Instead of dynamically loading in the scripts, I just put them straight into the head of my HTML page. I could probably add into my scripts file a check to see if the external libraries are loaded, but I think it was going to end up being a lot of extra, unnecessary work.

For future visitors to this question, the order of the scripts below is absolutely necessary in order for anything with Knockout to work. Also, it's worth noting that jQuery tmpl loads slower than Knockout.js. When I attempted to dynamically load them in, I had functions that would fire when the external libraries finished loading. Even though tmpl was listed first, Knockout was always loading first (unless the browser handles the last alert FIRST, and then rolls back to previous alerts...please correct me if this is wrong).

```
    <head>
        <title>Search Prototype</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/master/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Comment: Are you sure you even need jquery-tmpl? The code in your question isn't using it anywhere. Also, you're pointing to `https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/master/jquery.tmpl.js` which won't be parsed because github serves it as `text/plain`. If you really want to use jquery-tmpl (note that the library is deprecated!!) use this url instead: `https://rawgithub.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/master/jquery.tmpl.js`. Can't be used in production and I highly advice you to not use that library and simply use Knockout's internal template engine, which you are already doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using AMD like require.js to load the scripts in the order.